# AWS Instance Upgrade CPanel/WHM Website Does not work

Tags: amazon-web-services, instance, upgrade, cpanel, default

I have an AWS instance with WHM/Cpanel installed on it.

I had upgraded the instance from Micro to Small, did backup the EBS and reattached it, I also reattached the Public IP and Setup the Previous Private IP to the new volume.

I am able to login to CPanel, can login via ssh, but when I open my websites hosted on this instance, I get a CPanel Default Page error, it does not loads the actual homepage of my website.

My Checklist -

1. Old Volume attached
2. Old Public IP Attached
3. Old Private IP attached (as Secondary IP)

What else I am missing

Can you please help

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It was Easy.

I went to WHM -> IP Functions -> IP Migration Wizard and then I put the new local ip and it fixed up everything

Thanks for looking into this.